# Using PathSegment with @PathParam against specifications in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am in the process of learning JAX-RS. While reading up on it and reading books about it, multiple times I've read examples like the following:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.PathSegment;

@Path("/read")
@Stateless
@Produces("text/plain")
public class MinimalExample
{
  @GET
  @Path("/b/{file}")
  public String readFile2(@PathParam("file") List<PathSegment> fileParam)
  {
    return fileParam.toString();
  }
}
```

(Sometimes `PathSegment` is a `List<PathSegment>` instead, but this is not relevant right now.)
When reproducing the example Eclipse throws up an error, telling me:

> The type 'javax.ws.rs.core.PathSegment' is not valid for this parameter. See JAX-RS 2.0 Specification (section 3.2) for more information.

I looked up the Specification in question and indeed, it confirms this. `PathSegment` is an interface which has neither `valueOf` nor `fromString`. None of the examples provided a `ParamConverterProvider`.

> Valid parameter types for each of the above annotations are listed in the corresponding Javadoc, however in
>   general (excluding @Context) the following types are supported:
>   1. Types for which a `ParamConverter` is available via a registered `ParamConverterProvider`. See
>   Javadoc for these classes for more information. 
>   2. Primitive types.
>   3. Types that have a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument.
>   4. Types that have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` with a single `String` argument
>   that return an instance of the type. If both methods are present then `valueOf` MUST be used unless
>   the type is an enum in which case `fromString` MUST be used.
>   5. `List<T>`, `Set<T>`, or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 1, 3 or 4 above.

This is in contrast to the JavaEE specification which also allows PathSegment [as shown here](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/) as a valid type.
Can someone explain to me how exactly all these JAX-RS examples do use PathSegment when it is against JAX-RS specification? I cannot imagine this to be a simple error because it's far too widespread and I have yet to see any comments complaining their examples do not work.

EDIT: I have determined that some of the more complete examples actually do build when using `mvn install` but not when using Eclipse. This leads me to believe it might have to do less with JAX-RS itself and more with some of my Eclipse settings. However, I'm stumped where to look exactly and even more confused - why do the examples build while not conforming to the JAX-RS specifications?

Comment: If you get this error at build time in Eclipse, then it's simply that you have some Eclipse plugin or additional check that is misleading you. The Java compiler can't possibly make such a check.

Comment: You're right, the error is not build stopping and seems to be an oversight in the JAX-RS-Validator of the JBoss plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've read my own quote more carefully (emphasis mine):

> Valid parameter types for each of the above annotations are listed in the **corresponding Javadoc**, however **in general** (excluding @Context) the following types are supported:
>   ...

After checking the Javadoc I confirmed that `@PathParam` indeed does allow `PathSegment` as a type.
The error itself seems to come from the JAX-RS-Validator of the JBoss Eclipse plugin. 
An up to date version of the plugin does not display the error.